# Changing a TextView in RecyclerView with if-else statement depending on a value from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a game where the current user sees all his current games in a RecyclerView (see picture). For that I am using the Firestore UI, and I want to change a TextView to "Play" or "Wait" depending whether the current user has to play or the opponent has to play. For that I made a field "turn" in the document where the RecyclerViewAdapter retrieves its value and give it the value of the UID of the current player or the opponent (depends who has to play).

So when the current user has to play he should see "Play" as TextView in the RecyclerView item and the opponent has to see "Wait" (see pictures). To get the desired result I wanted to implement an if-else statement, but unfortunately `textViewTurn.getText().toString()`in the if statement has no value but it has one when I am sending the value to the next Activity as intent, so my if else statement is not working. How do I get the value of this TextView within the `CurrentGamesHolder`? Should I use the if else statement somewhere else in the RecyclerAdapter?

**Edit:**
I now moved the if else statement into the `onBindViewHolder` where both `mTurn`and `uid`have a value but the method is still not working. That means when I log in to the account of the Player 1 the `textViewPlay` shows "Wait" which is the same as the Player 2. The value of the `uid` is different in both accounts so I actually don't know how it is possible that the outcome in both accounts is the same, as according to the if else statement it shouldn't be.

Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class CurrentGameAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<CurrentGames, CurrentGameAdapter.CurrentGamesHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public CurrentGameAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<CurrentGames> options) {
        super(options);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CurrentGamesHolder holder, int position, @NonNull CurrentGames model) {

        holder.textViewTurn.setText(model.getTurn());
        holder.textViewPlay.setText("");
           ...

        mTurn = model.getTurn();


        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String mCurrentUser =currentUser.getUid();

        if (mTurn == mCurrentUser){
            holder.textViewPlay.setText("Play");
        }else if (mTurn != mCurrentUser){
            holder.textViewPlay.setText("Wait");
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CurrentGamesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem_current_game,parent, false);
        return new CurrentGamesHolder(view);
    }

    class CurrentGamesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewTurn, textViewPlay;

         ...


        public CurrentGamesHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewPlay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_current_game);
            textViewTurn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.turn_current_game);
            textViewTurn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            ...

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position),(position));
                        Intent i = new Intent (itemView.getContext(), PlayInterimResultMainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("turn", textViewTurn.getText().toString());
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(i);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

The first picture is what the player sees in his RecyclerView when he has to play and the second is what the opponent sees:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long trying I found the solution. I used the == operator, which compares the two object's references, not the Strings. To compare Strings I have to use `.equals()`. I was surprised since Android Studio displayed me "Strings are compared using '==' not 'equals()', so maybe there is a bug in that.

Here is the right if-else statement:

```
if (mTurn.equals(uid)){
            holder.textViewPlay.setText("Wait");
        }else {
            holder.textViewPlay.setText("Play");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView creates views (by calling the constructor) only for the views that fits the screen, and then populates it with your data based on wich objects that fits on the screen (with the onBindViewHolder method).

Your if-else block is inside your ViewHolder constructor and in that moment, you hadn't bind it yet. In that moment, the text in your textviews is the text you placed in your xml file, and that is why it is empty. That if-else statement should be in the onBindViewHolder method instead.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, but I don't know how to implement the if-else statement in the onBindViewHolder.(See my updated question)